# Как правильно передать переменную через поток?

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt5, pyqt

Есть класс (для краткости все лишнее убрал):

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread
import requests
import json
import time


class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)

        self.threadClass = ThreadClass()
        self.threadClass.start()

        self.url_base = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/'
        self.main_id = 0
        self.usr_id = 0

    #тут метод класса, который делает запрос на сервер 
    def rewrite(self):
        print('hhh')
        url = self.url_base + 'blog/chat/{}/{}'.format(self.usr_id, self.main_id)
        # print(url)
        r = requests.post(url)
```

Другой класс в отдельном потоке:

```
class ThreadClass(QThread):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)

    def run(self):
        while True:
            MyWindow.rewrite(MyWindow)
            #print('hi')
            time.sleep(1)
```

Проблема в том, что при запуске выдает ошибку

> AttributeError: type object 'MyWindow' has no attribute 'url_base'

В строке метода `rewrite()` где в `url` передается переменная `url_base`, эта переменная почему-то не видна.

Подозреваю, что переменные между потоками надо передавать через сигналы, пытался это сделать, но не получается.

Прошу подсказать, как это сделать?

Comment: Как минимум, параметр `self` должен указывать на экземпляр класса, а не сам класс.

Comment: Sergey Gornostaev, можно ли поподробнее, в какой строчке?

Comment: Я как понял, выше комментатор имел ввиду вот - это MyWindow.rewrite(MyWindow). Вы в метод передаете MyWindow, ничего туда не надо передавать. Ну вообще почему не MyWindow().rewrite? Вы пытаетесь вызвать метод из класса не создавая сам объект MyWindow.

Comment: Sonic Myst, спасибо за пояснение, но тогда выдает ошибку, что надо передать self, передаю и возвращаюсь к первоначальной ошибке.

Comment: Попробуйте MyWindow().rewrite().

Comment: Короче говоря, вы получите бесконечный цикл, но похоже не этого вы добивались?)

Comment: вроде что-то получилось, спасибо большое)

Comment: @ZaurK, вы уверены что в не в потоке хотите `r = requests.post(url)` выполнять, а результат в главный поток отправлять? :)

Comment: gil9red, вроде бы так и задумано) делать в потоке запрос request и обновлять виджет в главном окне. Вы имеете в виду перенести запрос из метода rewrite в поток?

Comment: @SonicMyst, нет-нет-нет, не надо вот этого `MyWindow().rewrite()`. Ведь получается, что каждый экземпляр класса `MyWindow` порождает экземпляр класса `ThreadClass`, который в свою очередь в бесконечном цикле начнет плодить экземпляры `MyWindow`, что уводит выполнение в бесконечную рекурсию.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Предлагаю перенести логику отправки в сам поток.

А результат запроса в главный поток передавать через сигналы-слоты. Для этого можно создать наследника от `QThread` и создать сигнал через тип `pyqtSignal`

Пример:

```
import sys
import time

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget
from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread, pyqtSignal

import requests


class ThreadClass(QThread):
    about_response = pyqtSignal(object)

    def __init__(self, url: str):
        super().__init__()

        self.url = url

    def run(self):
        while True:
            try:
                rs = requests.post(self.url)
                self.about_response.emit(rs)

            except Exception as e:
                print('Error:', e)

            finally:
                time.sleep(1)


class MyWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.url_base = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/'
        self.main_id = 0
        self.usr_id = 0

        url = self.url_base + 'blog/chat/{}/{}'.format(self.usr_id, self.main_id)

        self.thread_class = ThreadClass(url)
        self.thread_class.about_response.connect(self.on_response)
        self.thread_class.start()

    def on_response(self, rs):
        print('on_response:', rs)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    application = QApplication(sys.argv)
    
    main_window = MyWindow()
    main_window.setGeometry(100, 100, 600, 600)
    main_window.show()

    sys.exit(application.exec_())
```

---

**PS.**

Вариант с обращением к экземпляру `MyWindow` и вызову у него того метода работает, но заслуга, похоже, в этом исключительно к [Global Interpreter Lock (GIL)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Interpreter_Lock), в других реализациях тот код ошибку будет вызывать.

Использование механизма сигналов-слотов, считаю, является предпочтительнее

Comment: gil9red, спасибо, попробую разобраться и отпишусь

Comment: @gil9red, а то я не увижу ваш комментарий если не под моим ответом он )

Comment: я не очень тут ориентируюсь)

Comment: @ZaurK, ничего страшного. Если что-то непонятно, не стесняйтесь задавать вопросы (в комментариях под нужной темой или создав тут вопрос)

Comment: gil9red, сделал по вашей схеме, с дополнениями, получаю запросы с интервалом. Спасибо большое)

Comment: @ZaurK, на здоровье :)

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread
import requests
import json
import time

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication


class ThreadClass(QThread):
    def __init__(self, window, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.window = window

    def run(self):
        while True:
            self.window.rewrite()
            #print('hi')
            time.sleep(1)

class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)

        self.threadClass = ThreadClass(self)
        self.threadClass.start()

        self.url_base = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/'
        self.main_id = 0
        self.usr_id = 0

    #тут метод класса, который делает запрос на сервер
    def rewrite(self):
        print('hhh')
        url = self.url_base + 'blog/chat/{}/{}'.format(self.usr_id, self.main_id)
        print(url)
        # r = requests.post(url)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    application = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main_window = MyWindow()
    main_window.setGeometry(100,100,600,600)
    main_window.show()

    sys.exit(application.exec_())
```

Comment: `QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)` у потока? Вы серьезно? :) Вообще, зачем так писать, если есть простая конструкция через `super()`? `super().__init__(parent)` и все

Comment: я новичок в питоне, не обессудьте:)

Comment: Sonic Myst, спасибо большое! вроде у меня запросы на сервер пошли, остались другие моменты, попытаюсь сам разобраться

Comment: Потом уже увидел, что это еще у автора пошло, но, в принципе, у вас такая же фигня как у автора, так что это и вас касается :)

Comment: Да, я только добавил кое-что. В остальном не стал разбираться.

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант:

```
import sys
import requests
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread, pyqtSignal

class ThreadClass(QThread):
    threadSignal = pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self, url_base, main_id, usr_id, parent=None):
        super().__init__()
        self.url_base, self.main_id, self.usr_id = url_base, main_id, usr_id

    def run(self):
        QThread.msleep(3000) # имитируем работу потока
        self.rewrite()

    #тут метод класса, который делает запрос на сервер 
    def rewrite(self):
#        url = '{}blog/chat/{}/{}'.format(self.url_base, self.usr_id, self.main_id)
        url = self.url_base
        print(url)
#        r = "requests.post(url)"
        r = requests.get(url)

        if r.status_code == 200:
            self.threadSignal.emit('Web site exists')
        else:
            self.threadSignal.emit('Web site does not exist')         


class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__()

        self.label    = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.url_base = QtWidgets.QLineEdit("https://pyqt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/") #('http://127.0.0.1:5000/')
        self.main_id  = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.usr_id   = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Отправить запрос")
        btn.clicked.connect(self.btnClicked)

        form     = QtWidgets.QFormLayout(self)
        form.addRow(self.label)
        form.addRow("url_base", self.url_base)
        form.addRow("main_id", self.main_id)
        form.addRow("usr_id", self.usr_id)
        form.addRow(btn)

    def btnClicked(self):
        self.threadClass = ThreadClass(self.url_base.text(), 
                                       self.main_id.text(), 
                                       self.usr_id.text())
        self.threadClass.threadSignal.connect(self.thSignal)
        self.threadClass.start()

    def thSignal(self, text):
        print(text)
        self.label.setText(text)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: S. Nick, спасибо, буду со всеми вариантами разбираться